# ImageMagick fill color with pattern

Tags: colors, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I want to replace specific colours with some patterns using `ImageMagick`.

I have a simplified example of what I would like to do.
Here I would like to replace the `red` colour with the pattern `pattern:right30`.

Here the image input is called `test.png`.

So far, I got

```
magick test.png -fuzz 40%  -tile pattern:right30 -opaque red room1.jpg
```

[image]

The issue is that my code gives me a black bar instead of the pattern.

[image]

The **output** I am looking for

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in Imagemagick by creating a tiling image of your pattern and a mask image and compositing over the input.

Input:

[image]

```
convert bar_graph.png \
\( -clone 0 -tile pattern:right30  -draw "color 0,0 reset" \) \
\( -clone 0 -fuzz 40% -fill black +opaque red -fill white -opaque red \) \
-compose over -composite bar_graph_tiled.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I couldn’t figure out. How do you adjust the size of the pattern, to make it more visible for instance ?

Comment: I get the following error `RGB color space not permitted on grayscale PNG bar_graph_tiled.png @ warning/png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1526.`

Comment: Not an error - just a warning.  You can suppress warnings by adding -quiet after convert and before the input. (The mask is black/white, ie. grayscale and PNG does not like IM making it RGB to match your color image)

Comment: @fmw42 I am getting the same issue, but the output is wrong too. Bar_graph_tiled is just the pattern without that actual graph.

Comment: It works fine on IM 6.9.12.98, but needs an edit on 7.1.1.21.  Add `-type truecolor` inside and at the end of the last parenthesis. So \\( -clone 0 -fuzz 40% -fill black +opaque red -fill white -opaque red -type tricolor \) \